# What's the correct syntax for a mongo dump of a specific date range?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using the below query for my mongo data dump:

```
`mongodump --db testdb --collection testc --out Instance.json --query '{"Created":{"$gte":{"$date":"2023-09-29T00:00:00.000Z"},"$lt":{"$date":"2023-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"}}}'`
```

However I'm getting:

```
Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add escaped double quotes in the query.
This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977309/mongoexport-issue-with-json-query-extended-json-invalid-json-input

Comment: When I copy/paste that command from the question (without the backticks) it works fine